# How do I strip \n characters from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, sed, newline

I have a question that should make most people go "WTF?", but I have it nonetheless.

I've got a bunch of data files from a vendor. It's in a custom flat-file format that claims to be CSV, except it's not comma separated, and values are not quoted. So, not really CSV at all.

```
foo,bar,baz
alice,bob,chris
```

And so on, except much longer and less interesting. The problem is, some records have embedded newlines (!!!):

```
foo,bar
rab,baz
alice,bob,chris
```

That is supposed to be two records of three fields each. Normally, I would just say "No, this is stupid.", but I inadvisedly looked closer, and discovered that it was actually a different kind of end of line than the actual line ending sequence:

```
foo,bar\n
rab,baz\r\n
alice,bob,chris\r\n
```

Note the \n on the first line. I've determined that this holds for all the cases I found of embedded newlines. So, I need to basically do `s/\n$//` (I tried this specific command, it did not do anything).

Note: I don't actually care about the *contents* of the fields, so replacing a newline with nothing is fine. I just need each line in the file to have the same number of records (ideally, in the same place).

I have an existing solution in the tool I wrote to process the files:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

string data = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin1"));
data = data.Replace("\r\n", g.ToString()); //just so I have a unique placeholder
data = data.Replace("\n", "");
data = data.Replace(g.ToString(), "\r\n");
```

However, this fails on files that are bigger than a gigabyte or so. (Also, I haven't profiled it, but I suspect it's dog slow as well).

The tools I have at my disposal are:

- cygwin tools (sed, grep, etc)
- .NET

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n ?

Comment: You could also replace `\r` with nothing, and then replace `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: Looks like normal CSV to me (except for the embedded newlines). Unquoted fields are totally normal.

Comment: Note: There was a typo in the title of the question. I want to replace `\n` with nothing, and `\r\n` with `\r\n` (eg, leave it alone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of reading the entire thing into memory as a big (potentially huge) string, consider a stream based approach instead.

Open the input stream and read a line at a time, making your replacements as needed.  Open an output stream and write the modified line into it.  Something like:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    using( var inFs = File.OpenRead( @"C:\input.txt" ) )
    using( var reader = new StreamReader( inFs ) )
    using( var outFs = File.Create( @"C:\output.txt" ) )
    using( var writer = new StreamWriter( outFs ) )
    {
        int cur;
        char last = '0';
        while( ( cur = reader.Read() ) != -1 )
        {
            char next = (char)reader.Peek();
            char c = (char)cur;
            if( c != '\n' || last == '\r' )
                writer.Write( c );

            last = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This!  You are going to run into memory/speed problems otherwise with massive files like this.

Comment: He wants to keep `\r\n` and drop only `\r` when it's by itself.

Comment: @JonB: Oh, yep, thanks, I misread his example.  Regardless, the method is the same.  I will whip up some sample code.

Comment: This won't work. `TextReader.ReadLine` will read up to any end of line sequence, including `\n` or `\r` by themselves.  It also won't return the EOL sequence, so this will just strip out all newlines.

Comment: Also, there is a typo in the question title. It should be `\n`, not `\r`

Comment: @MikeCaron: D'oh, and that's what I get for changing it at the last moment (I was reading character by character in the first example).  I'll fix it, thanks

Comment: @MikeCaron: That part I got; he wants to remove '\n'.  The code is (trying to) remove all \r's and then replacing the remaining \n's with \r\n.

Comment: @EdS.: I'm he :) And, that won't work, because that will turn all the `\r\n` sequences into `\n`, which is identical to the sequences I want to remove. Doing it the other way (replace `\n` with "" and turn `\r` into `\r\n`) would work. If you could show me an easy way to do that, I would be grateful

Comment: @MikeCaron: Ahh, so you are :). You need to do this character by character anyway, so it's a matter of replacing \n when the previous character was not \r.  The stream approach will at least fix your program, the rest is just details.

Comment: @MikeCaron: Ok, meeting was delayed by 5 so I had time to fix it.

Comment: That looks good! I ended up doing it slightly differently (see my answer below), but I'll accept yours since your solution is actually slightly more accurate to the question than mine :)

Comment: @MikeCaron: Ok, thanks. I wanted to make sure I got it right; remove all \n's unless they are grouped as \r\n, right? :D

Answer (score 3):

That's an awful lot of code to do something so simple.

Try this instead.

```
tr -d '\n' <dirtyfile >cleanfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `StreamReader` class that seems to do what I want. Note that this is probably incredibly domain specific, so it may or may not be useful:

```
class BadEOLStreamReader : StreamReader {
    private int pushback = -1;

    public BadEOLStreamReader(string file, Encoding encoding) : base(file, encoding) {

    }

    public override int Peek() {
        if (pushback != -1) {
            var r = pushback;
            pushback = -1;
            return r;
        }

        return base.Peek();
    }

    public override int Read() {
        if (pushback != -1) {
            var r = pushback;
            pushback = -1;
            return r;
        }

        skip:
        var ret = base.Read();
        if (ret == 13) {
            var ret2 = base.Read();
            if (ret2 == 10) {
                //it's good, push back the 10
                pushback = ret2;
                return ret;
            }
            pushback = ret2;
            //skip it
            goto skip;
        } else if (ret == 10) {
            //skip it
            goto skip;
        } else {

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: after some tests, the awk solution gives better results in terms of speed.

The standard file/input filter in UNIX/Linux/Cygwin have a hard time dealing with binary file.  To do that with filters, you need to convert your file in HEX, edit it with `sed` (or `awk`, see 2nd solution bellow), and convert it back to its original data.  This should do it:

```
xxd -c1 -p file.txt | 
  sed -n -e '1{h}' -e '${x;G;p;d}' \
      -e '2,${x;G;/^0d\n0a$/{P;b};/\n0a$/{P;s/.*//;x;b};P}' |
  xxd -r -p
```

Ok, this is not simple to understand, let's begin with the simple parts:

- `xxd -c1 -p file.txt` converts `file.txt` from binary to HEX, one byte per line.
- `xxd -r -p` reverts the convertion.
- The `sed` replaces a `\n` (0a in HEX) that is not preceded by a `\r` (0d in HEX) by nothing.

The idea of the `sed` part is to store the previous byte in the hold space, and to deal with both the previous and the current byte:

- At the 1st line, store the line (byte) in the hold space.
- At the last line, print both bytes in the correct order (`x;G;p`) and stop the script (`d`).
- For the lines in between, after having the current byte in the hold space and the 2 bytes (previous and current) in the pattern space (`x;G`), 3 possibles cases:

  1. If is a `\r\n`, then print `\r` keeping `\n` in the hold space for the next cycle and stop this cycle (`b` command).
  2. Else if it ends with `\n` (meaning that it did not begin by `\r`) store an empty string in the hold space and stop this cycle (`b` command)
  3. Else print the 1st character.

It might be simpler to understand in `awk`:

```
xxd -c1 -p file.txt |
  awk 'NR > 1 && $0 == "0a" && p != "0d" {$0 = ""}
       NR > 1 {print p}
       {p = $0}
       END{print p}' |
  xxd -r -p
```

It can be tested with:

```
printf "foo,bar\nrab,baz\r\nalice,bob,chris\r\n" |
  xxd -c1 -p | 
  sed -n -e '1{h}' -e '${x;G;p;d}' \
      -e '2,${x;G;/^0d\n0a$/{P;b};/\n0a$/{P;s/.*//;x;b};P}' |
  xxd -r -p
```

or

```
printf "foo,bar\nrab,baz\r\nalice,bob,chris\r\n" |
  xxd -c1 -p |
  awk 'NR > 1 && $0 == "0a" && p != "0d" {$0 = ""}
       NR > 1 {print p}
       {p = $0}
       END{print p}' |
  xxd -r -p
```

Comment: An interesting (and thoroughly incomprehensible :) solution, but does it scale? Eg, if I need to process a 2gb data file, should I grab lunch?

Comment: Incomprehensible: True, the sed part is not the easiest to understand.    Did you understand the usage of xxd and then the idea of removing orphan `\n`.  The awk solution might be easier to understand, but less efficient.

Comment: Does it scale: yes, it can deal with any size of input.  Is it efficient: it depends on your point of view.  The 1st xxd convert a 2 Gb binary file to a 6 Gb text file with one byte per line which is a lot a data.  Then, each byte is read one at a time to decide if it need to be kept or not.  sed and awk are probably not the best tool to do that with speed, but if you are not a programmer or if you do not have access to a compiler, they probably are the only solution you have.

Comment: If you want a fast solution, writing a well optimized program in C or Java (or Perl or Python, but I do not know those last 2) will solve the problem quick, but if it is a one time file processing, waiting a little might be a less painful solution.

Comment: A last thought, this solution breaks when using multi-bytes character sets (UNICODE).

Comment: About efficiency, the awk solution score 6 seconds on my laptop for 3.3 Mb file and I stop the sed solution after 60 seconds, so the awk solution is better.
On a 13 Mb file, the awk solution score a little less than 24 seconds.
On a 52 Mb file, it scores a 93 seconds.
So I guess that it would take an hour with your 2 Gb file.

Comment: I am not a sed/awk/etc guru, so anything fancier than `s/x/y/g` is incomprehensible :) Anyway, I ended up going with a solution that removed the new lines as the file was streamed which seems to be pretty efficient, but thanks anyway!